# Consulta por consulta de sql (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo 2 tablas, la primera, de `cursos` que tiene las columnas `idCurso`, `Nombre`, `Descripcion`, y una segunda, llamada `cursos_Comentarios`, que tiene el id, `idCurso`(fk) y el comentario de cada curso...
El tema es que quiero traer toda la info de la tabla cursos y ademas cuantos comentarios tiene la misma, hice lo siguiente con lo que recuerdo de sql:

```
SELECT c.IdCurso, COUNT(c.IdCurso) as 'Cantidad_comentarios' from cursos c 
INNER JOIN cursos_comentarios cc
ON c.IdCurso = cc.idCurso GROUP BY c.IdCurso
```

pero no obtengo lo que espero, me tira todo en blanco.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Podrías hacer una subconsulta en el select que haga el conteo. Ya que al usar INNER JOIN obligas a que exista almenos un comentario del curso sino no te mostrará resultados, arreglando quedaría así con una subconsulta:

```
SELECT
      c.idCurso,
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cursos_comentarios cc WHERE cc.idCurso = c.idCurso) AS 'Cantidad_comentarios'
FROM cursos c
```

Con eso tendrás el listado de los cursos y la cantidad de comentarios por cada curso.

Comment: Funciono genial!!!! Muchas gracias!!!